# acts_as_xslx: undefined method `to_xlsx' for #<String:0x007f206b7daf90>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Some of you guys ever used the gem 'acts_as_xslx'? https://github.com/randym/acts_as_xlsx

## model

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_xlsx
```

## controller

```
tasks = @organization.tasks

respond_to do |format|
  format.xlsx {
         send_data tasks.report(start_period, end_period).to_xlsx.to_stream.read, :filename => 'posts.xlsx', :type => "application/vnd.openxmlformates-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
     }
```

## ErrorMessage

> undefined method `to_xlsx' for # string:0x007f206b7daf90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tasks[0].to_xlsx.to_stream.read, :filename => 'posts.xlsx', :type => "application/vnd.openxmlformates-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
```

to_xlsx is duck-typed on ActiveRecord, not String, at least according to [the test](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/randym/acts_as_xlsx/master/test/tc_acts_as_xlsx.rb).